# Apache2 PHP Notice errors logged

Tags: apache-2.2, php, log-files, mod-fcgid

My /var/log/apache2/error.log is filling up about 1GB per hour with PHP Notice errors.

I've tried adding this:
/apache2.conf

```
php_value error_log none
```

And in my /cgi/php.ini:

```
error_reporting = E_ERROR
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = Off
```

PHP is running through fcgi.
Even though display errors is ON, it is NOT displaying errors.

Is there a seperate config file I should be editting?

OS: Ubuntu Linux 10.04
PHP: 5.3.2
Apache: 2.2.14

Comment: Can you please provide details about the OS, distribution, and versions of php?

Comment: OS: Ubuntu Linux 10.04
PHP: 5.3.2
Apache: 2.2.14

Answer (score 0):

Check where `DefaultInitEnv PHPRC=` is pointing and change the logging in that configuration file. I think it should be `/etc/php5/php.ini`.

Comment: I can't find any configuration files for fcgi :/

Comment: If it is not a production server, then restart apache so that php will reread the configuration file and search for a php.ini that was accessed in the last few minutes: `find /etc -type f -amin 10`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE`

in your php.ini

Comment: This didn't work, I'm pretty sure my ini file isn't being used.